# NSCondtion with multiple threads

Tags: objective-c, locking, signals, nscondition, ios-multithreading

**method1:**

```
 - (void) method1
 {
    [_condition lock];

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5 * NSEC_PER_MSEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         //Fetach data from remote, when finished call method2
         [self fetchData]; 
    });

    [_condition waitUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:30.0]];

    // Do something.
    [_condition unlock];
}
```

**method2:**

```
- (void) method2
 {
    [_condition lock];
    [_condition signal];
    [_condition unlock];
}
```

If **Thread 1** is in method1, by executing `[_condition waitUtilDate ...];` it unlocks its lock.   **Thread 2**  entered this area and also wait on the condition by executing `[_condition waitUtilDate ...]`.

Both **Thread 1** and **Thread 2** enqueued a Block(**request 1** **request 2**)   to fetch the same data from remote. When **request 1** finishes, it calls method2 to signal _condition:

### My questions are:

- Which will be signaled, **Thread 1** or **Thread 2** ?
- 'cause **request 1** and **request 2** are doing the same thing, I can signal both threads(`broadcast`) and cancel **request 2** when **request 1** finishes. But, a better way is to refuse **Thread 2** to enter the critical area, after  **request 1** is sent out. But I coundn't lock twice before entering the critical area. So what can I do?

**Thanks.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to prevent duplicate requests you can do this with a boolean flag that you set when starting the request and then clear when you're done.  You'd protect your critical regions with a mutex/semaphore/NSLock/etc.

```
[_lock lock];
if (_fetching) {
   [_lock unlock];
   return;
}

_fetching = YES;

[self startRequestWithCompletion: ^{ 
   [_lock lock];
   _fetching = NO;
   [_lock unlock]; 
}];

[_lock unlock];
```

Or you can use an NSOperationQueue and NSOperation to handle this more elegantly.  You'd test the queue to see if there are any pending or running operations before starting a new one.

```
if (_operationQueue.operationCount)
    return;

[_operationQueue addOperationWithBlock: ^{
    // get your data
}];
```

How you do this really depends on exactly what you're fetching and whether the response may change based on input data. For example, I use NSOperations extensively to manage background computations.  However, user input could change the result of those computations and invalidate any previous work.  I hang on to a reference the NSOperation itself so I can cancel it and restart a new one where appropriate.